# Выбор пространства имен в зависимости от аргумента функции

Tags: c++, namespace

Здравствуйте!
В рамках знакомства с SDL2 я создаю пробный проект. Одним из ключевых моментов данной работы является использование собственных пространств имен в зависимости от "уровня" приложения. Например, уровень 'Основное меню' должен использовать пространство имен 'menu', уровень 'Настройки' использует пространство имен 'menu::settings' и так далее. Пространства имен описаны в области глобальных переменных и и имеют типовое описание.
Файл глобальных переменных 'global_variables.h':

```
#include "stdafx.h"

//Screen dimension constants
const int SCREEN_WIDTH[] = {800, 1024, 1280};
const int SCREEN_HEIGHT[] = {600, 768, 1024};

short num_of_level = 1;     // Counter of levels

// SCR number
short nom_scr = 0;          // Screen mode variable;
                            // 0 - 800x600
                            // 1 - 1024x768
                            // 2 - 1280x1024
// Check of resolution changing
bool res_change = false;
// Sound volume
short sound_vol = 0;

// Menu variables
namespace menu
{
    const short N = 4;
    const short M = 1;
    // Positions of button: the First dimension - number of button, the Second dimension is number of times screen resolution
    // "START" - button, "LOAD" - button, "SETTINGS" - button, "EXIT" - button
    const short BUT_POS_X[N][3] = { { 560, 756, 980 }, {560, 756, 980}, {560, 756, 980}, {560, 756, 980} };
    const short BUT_POS_Y[N][3] = { { 200, 256, 342 }, {279, 305, 441}, {358, 394, 540}, {437, 483, 639} };
    // States of buttons
    const short BUT_STATE[N][3] = {{0, 75, 153}, {0, 75, 153}, {0, 75, 153}, {0, 75, 153}};
    const short BUT_SIZE[N][2] = {{140, 49}, {140, 49}, {140, 49}, {140, 49}};
    // If button is difficult (for example one has more than one active zone), then one element of following array will be more than 0, else - 0
    const short DIF_BUT[N] = {0, 0, 0, 0};
    // Coordinates of labels
    const short LAB_POS_X[M][3] = {{86, 198, 326}};
    const short LAB_POS_Y[M][3] = {{102, 186, 314}};
    // Labels size
    const short LAB_SIZE[M][2] = {{628, 396}};
    // If element of LAB_ANIM is true, then this texture is animation
    const bool LAB_ANIM[M] = {true};
    // Image length
    const short LAB_IMG[1] = {41};
    // Background color (Red, blue, green, alpha)
    short BG_Color[4] = {0, 0, 0, 0};
    // Thumb marker
    const bool IS_TH[M] = {false};
    // Menu pictures ways
    string WAYS[] = { "Resurses\\MENU_Y.png\0",
                        "Resurses\\BUT_NEW.png\0",
                        "Resurses\\BUT_LOAD.png\0",
                        "Resurses\\BUT_SET.png\0",
                        "Resurses\\BUT_EXIT.png\0" };   // [5]
    namespace load
    {
        //
    }
    namespace settings
    {
        const short N = 5;      // Number of buttons
        const short M = 3;      // Number of labels
        bool FULL_SC = false;
        short cur_sr, cur_vol;
        // "Screen resolution" - scroll, "Sound volume" - scroll, "Full screen" - check box,
        // "Ok" - button, "Cancel" - button
        const short BUT_POS_X[][3] = { {500, 696, 920}, {500, 696, 920}, {500, 696, 920}, {100, 100, 100}, {290, 304, 324} };  // [N][3]
        const short BUT_POS_Y[][3] = { {100, 128, 170}, {139, 173, 223}, {178, 218, 276}, {451, 580, 797}, {451, 580, 797} };  // [N][3]
        // States of buttons
        const short BUT_STATE[][3] = {{0, 39, 78}, {0, 39, 78}, {0, 29, 58}, {0, 75, 153}, {0, 75, 153}};  // [N][3]
        const short BUT_SIZE[][2] = {{200, 19}, {200, 19}, {200, 28}, {140, 49}, {140, 49}};       // [N][2]
        const short DIF_BUT[] = {2, 2, 0, 0, 0};    // [N]
        // X-coordinates of active zones boundaries.
        // The First dimension is button; the Second dimension is active zone; the Third dimension contains coordinates of current zone
        const short BUT_AREAS[][2][2] = {{{0, 20}, {180, 199}}, {{0, 20}, {180, 199}}};    // [2][2][2]
        // Image segments for each active zone. The First dimension is button; the Second dimension is active zone;
        const short BUT_SEGMENT[][2] = {{351, 0}, {117, 0}};   // [2][2]
        // Special array. It's nessesary for screen resolution button.
        const short BUT_ADVANCED[] = {117, 0};  // [2]
        // Coordinates of labels
        const short LAB_POS_X[][3] = {{86, 198, 326}, {250, 432, 640}, {250, 432, 640}, {500, 969, 920}};  // [M][3]
        const short LAB_POS_Y[][3] = {{102, 186, 314}, {100, 128, 170}, {139, 173, 223}, {100, 128, 170}}; // [M][3]
        // Labels size
        const short LAB_SIZE[][2] = {{628, 396}, {200, 30}, {200, 30}, {20, 7}}; // [M][2]
        // If element of LAB_ANIM is true, then this texture is animation
        const bool LAB_ANIM[] = {true, false, false, false};   //[M]
        // Image length
        const short LAB_IMG[] = {41};   //[1]
        // Thumb marker
        const bool IS_TH[] = {false, false, false, true};       // [M]
        // Positions of sound volume ("Sound thumb" - thumb)
        const short POS_TH_X[][13] = {19, 25, 31, 37, 43, 49, 55, 61, 67, 73, 79, 85, 91}; // [1][13]
        const short POS_TH_Y[][13] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};              // [1][13]
        // Settings menu pictures ways
        string WAYS[] = { "Resurses\\Sett\\MENU_Y.png\0",
                        "Resurses\\Sett\\SCR_RES.png\0",
                        "Resurses\\Sett\\SCR_RES.png\0",
                        "Resurses\\Sett\\THUMB.png\0",
                        "Resurses\\Sett\\THUMB.png\0",
                        "Resurses\\Sett\\BUT_OK.png\0",
                        "Resurses\\Sett\\BUT_CANC.png\0",
                        "Resurses\\Sett\\THUMB_fl.png\0",
                        "Resurses\\Sett\\TEXTS_V.png\0",
                        "Resurses\\Sett\\TEXTS_S.png\0" };      //[10]
    }
}

namespace game
{
    //
}

// string WAYS[5] = {"Resurses\\First\\BG.png\0", "Resurses\\First\\PLAYER.png\0"};
```

Заголовочный файл 'levels.h', где объявлен класс уровней

```
#pragma once
#ifndef _LEVEL_
#define _LEVEL_

#include "stdafx.h"

#include "global_variables.h"

class levels
{
public:
    levels(SDL_Renderer*, short, short[]);
    SDL_Renderer* level_processing(SDL_Renderer*, float, SDL_Rect[], short);
    ~levels();
private:
    // n - number of textures; ANIM - animation counter
    short n, ANIM, n_n, m_m;
    SDL_Renderer* BACKGR = nullptr;         // Background render
    SDL_Renderer* _ren = nullptr;               // Main renderer
    SDL_Rect rectBG;                        // Rect structure for background
    SDL_Rect *IMG = nullptr, *SUR = nullptr;
    char way[255];
    float bg[4];
    // _SUR_A - Rect structure, which contain coordinates of active buttons
    // _SUR_L - Rect structure, which contain coordinates of labels
    // _IMG_A - Rect structure, which contain coordinates of position on image for active button
    // _IMG_L - Rect structure, which contain coordinates of position on image for labels
    // SIZE_A - This array contain states;
    // N_ANIM - Array, which contain numbers of frames;
    // ANIM_X - This array defines type label (Is it animation or not);
    SDL_Rect *_IMG_A = nullptr, *_SUR_A = nullptr;
    SDL_Rect *_IMG_L = nullptr, *_SUR_L = nullptr;
    short *N_ANIM = nullptr;
    bool *ANIM_X = nullptr;
    SDL_Surface* SURF = nullptr;
    SDL_Texture* TEXT = nullptr;
    void redraw_textures();
};

#endif // _LEVEL_
```

Файл описания класса уровней

```
 #include "levels.h"

    levels::levels(SDL_Renderer* rMain, short _num_lvl, short ident[])
    {
        switch(_num_lvl)
        {
        case 1:
            {using namespace menu;}
        case 2:
            {using namespace menu::load;}
        case 3:
            {using namespace menu::settings;}
        case 4:
            {using namespace game;}
        }
        short count = 0;
        n_n = N;
        m_m = M; ANIM = 0;
        _ren = rMain;
        TEXT = new SDL_Texture[N];
        _SUR_A = new SDL_Rect[N];   _SUR_L = new SDL_Rect[M];
        _IMG_A = new _SUR_A[N]; _IMG_L = new _SUR_A[M];
        ANIM_X = new bool[M];
        for(int i = 0; i < M; i++)
            ANIM_X[i] = LAB_ANIM[i];
        short G = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < M; i++)
            if(LAB_ANIM[i])
                G++;
        N_ANIM = new short[G];
        for(int i = 0; i < G; i++)
            N_ANIM[i] = LAB_IMG[i];
        for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            _SUR_A[i].x = BUT_POS_X[i][nom_scr];    _SUR_A[i].y = BUT_POS_Y[i][nom_scr];
            _SUR_A[i].w = BUT_SIZE[i][0]; _SUR_A[i].h = BUT_SIZE[i][1];
            _IMG_A[i].x = 0; _IMG_A[i].y = BUT_STATE[i][0] + ident[i];
            _IMG_A[i].w = BUT_SIZE[i][0]; _IMG_A.h = BUT_SIZE[i][1];
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < M; i++)
        {
            if(IS_TH[i])
            {
                _SUR_L[i].x = LAB_POS_X[i][nom_scr] + POS_TH_X[count][sound_vol];
                _SUR_L[i].y = LAB_POS_X[i][nom_scr] + POS_TH_Y[count][sound_vol];
                count++;
            }
            else
            {
                _SUR_L[i].x = LAB_POS_X[i][nom_scr];
                _SUR_L[i].y = LAB_POS_X[i][nom_scr];
            }
            _SUR_L[i].w = LAB_SIZE[i][0];
            _SUR_L[i].h = LAB_SIZE[i][1];
            _IMG_L[i].x = 0; _IMG_L[i].y = 0;
            _IMG_L[i].w = BUT_SIZE[i][0]; _IMG_L.h = BUT_SIZE[i][1];
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            bg[i] = BG_Color[i];
        for(int i = 0; i < n_n + m_m; i++)
        {
            std::memmove(way, WAYS[i].c_str(), WAYS[i].length());
            std::memmove(way + WAYS[i].length(), "\0", 1);
            SURF = IMG_Load(way);
            TEXT[i] = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(_ren, SURF);
            SDL_FreeSurface(SURF);
            SURF = NULL;
        }
    }

    SDL_Renderer* levels::level_processing(SDL_Renderer* rMain, float I, SDL_Rect _IMG[], short _num_lvl)
    {
        // rMain is render, in which will be copied textures
        // I is variable for animation
        // _IMG is array, which contain coordinates on image. It's necessary for buttons
        switch(_num_lvl)
        {
        case 1:
            {using namespace menu;}
        case 2:
            {using namespace menu::load;}
        case 3:
            {using namespace menu::settings;}
        case 4:


{using namespace game;}
    }
    _ren = rMain;
    short count = 0;
    // Thumb settings
    for(int i = 0; i < m_m; i++)
    {
        if(IS_TH[i])
        {
            _SUR_L[i].x = LAB_POS_X[i][nom_scr] + POS_TH_X[count][sound_vol];
            _SUR_L[i].y = LAB_POS_X[i][nom_scr] + POS_TH_Y[count][sound_vol];
            count++;
        }
    }
    // Animation settings
    count = 0;
    int J = int(I);
    for(int i = 0; i < M; i++)
        if(ANIM_X[i])
        {
            while (J >= LAB_IMG[count])
                J -= LAB_IMG[count];
            _IMG_L[i].y = J*LAB_SIZE[i][1];
            count++;
        }
    for(int i = 0; i < n_n; i++)
        _IMG_A[i].y = _IMG[i].y;
    redraw_textures();
    return _ren;
}

void levels::redraw_textures()
{
    SDL_RenderClear(_ren);
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(BACKGR, bg[0], bg[1], bg[2], bg[3]);
    SDL_RenderFillRect(BACKGR, &rectBG);
    for(int i = 0; i < n_n; i++)
        SDL_RenderCopy(_ren, TEXT[i], &_IMG_A[i], &_SUR_A[i]);
    for(int i = n_n; i < m_m; i++)
        SDL_RenderCopy(_ren, TEXT[i], &_IMG_L[i], &_SUR_L[i]);
    SDL_RenderPresent(_ren);
}

levels::~levels()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < n_n + m_m; i++)
        SDL_DestroyTexture(TEXT[i]);
    delete[] TEXT;
    TEXT = NULL;
    delete _ren;
    _ren = NULL;
    delete[] IMG;
    IMG = NULL;
    delete[] SURF;
    SURF = NULL;
    delete SURF;
    SURF = NULL;
    delete[] _IMG_A;    delete[] _IMG_L;
    delete[] _SUR_A;    delete[] _SUR_L;
    for(int i = 0; i < n_n; i++)
        delete[] SIZE_A[i];
    delete[] SIZE_A;
    SIZE_A = NULL;
    delete[] N_ANIM;
    N_ANIM = NULL;
    delete[] ANIM_X;
    ANIM_X = NULL;
}
```

В последнем листинге я пытался реализовать выбор пространства имен с помощью switch оператора.

Comment: Именно так не получится. Варианты switch выбираются на стадии выполнения, а using namespace работает на стадии компиляции.

Comment: Ну да. Я думал заменить пространства имен на классы, но как-то криво получается.

Answer (score 1):

Решено. Вместо выбора пространств имен стал осуществляться выбор объектов. Классы объектов являются наследниками основного класса, в котором содержатся объявления основных переменных, которые раньше объявлялись в пространствах имен. В классах-наследниках происходит инициализация полей, объявленных в базовом классе.